# css border around my div layout

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, border

Hi I'm running into a bit of trouble with my layout

I want to put a border around all the outside of the layout and when the browser is re-sized it will still be there. how would i do this without affecting the responsiveness of the layout and media queries? Was thinking maybe a border that's on the inside of the `div`?

also not sure what I've done but im getting a gap in my `<div>` you can see under the logo.

http://www.techagesite.com/page-1work11122.htm

Comment: What do you mean by *put a border around all the outside of the layout*? Can you provide a screenshot how you want to place border?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Have you looked into the box-sizing of your elements? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Also, please include simplified code within your question.

Comment: yeah sorry www.techagesite.com/shot.png and of course on the bottom too

Comment: @daze was a few weeks ago when i last attempted it so bit foggy. I guess i just tried putting a border on the div named box that contains the rest of the divs that make up the layout. When you say simplified do you mean elements without the content in them?

Comment: What's working, what's not working? When I say simplified code, I mean something that can give us the gist of what you're trying to do without extraneous/superfluous code. In doing so, you might even be able to troubleshoot your own problem yourself! Read the whathaveyoutried.com link I provided previously if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/mV642/1/)**</kbd>

css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
body {
    display: table-row;
}
.mainBody {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 10px solid blue;
}
```

Example html

```
<body>
    <div class="mainBody">all your content here</div>
</body>
```

**To add border to every element on page use universal selector '`*`'** as below:

```
* {
 border: 5px solid #3A5FCD;
}
```

**And finally cheers**, it was a simple edit but due to lack to understanding the problem it took such a long time, anyways your sample pic help me to realize your want.

Just replace your body{..} with

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

(remove display: table-cell, margin auto will make it horizontal center with max-width)

Comment: it works but its going around the whole page and not just the divs.

Comment: I have edited, you can change ID to Class, .forBorder, now add this class to every div you want to have border.

Comment: sorry i might not have been too clear. i need the border around everything like in the image i linked to

Comment: just add this to your css     
" * {
     border: 5px solid #3A5FCD;
    } "

Comment: that puts a border around everything.i need a border around the outside of my layout only but not around the background space left and right. have a look at this. this is how i want it http://www.techagesite.com/shot.png see how its around the layout but not the border

Comment: refer to my first answer, just add <div class="mainBody"> just below <body> of your code and </div> just above </body> of your code, and use the css mentioned.

Comment: i did that and it puts a border around the entire page not just the outside of my layout

Answer (score 1):

> also not sure what I've done but im getting a gap in my  you can
>   see under the logo.

Change the height attribute of box2 or box3 to match each other.
Currently,the height for box2 is 179px and box 3 is 203px. So make height of box2 to203px or change height for box3 to 179px.

Comment: i havent got a height on the box2 and 3

Comment: So the default height is set to auto and the div tag is adjusted where the image ends. Set the heights to make them equal.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Comment: You not not give any css to height property. So the default is `height:auto;`. This make the height of both box2 and box3 different for different browsers. Give them a fix height like `height:179px;`.

Comment: wont that mess up a responsive layout?

Comment: Check this out [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/fGf7E/2/). Uncomment the height property and check. It levels the 2 box and does not effect other elements.

Comment: from a few browser resize tests it appears to work correct cheers